# how to pass keyboard input to a constructor?

Tags: java

How could I pass the input from the user in the constructor for further workings, should i use bufferedreader or not

```
Constructor(String nameClient, String idClient)


BufferedReader obj=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
try {
    System.out.println("Insert some name: ");
    String nameClient=obj.readLine();
    System.out.println("Insert some id: ");
    String idClient=obj.readLine();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: I recommend doing some research into some basic tutorials, or googling it more as there will be plenty of information for this online. You will learn very slowly if every time you have a slight hiccup you resort to asking a question online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the constructor while creating an object.

I have given below an example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class SomeClass {
    String nameClient;
    String idClient;

    public SomeClass(String nameClient, String idClient) {
        this.nameClient = nameClient;
        this.idClient = idClient;
    }
    // ...
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("Insert some name: ");
            String nameClient = obj.readLine();
            System.out.println("Insert some id: ");
            String idClient = obj.readLine();
            SomeClass someObj = new SomeClass(nameClient, idClient);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for more information.

Comment: Please don't encourage people to post sloppy questions by answering them.

Comment: nailed it, thx!!!

Comment: You are most welcome, @G.Weiss